# Server response with error 500 on AJAX file POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

StackOverflow!
I have an issue with file upload using jQuery. Everything works well on my localhost, but on remote I have a problem with $.ajax

Here is my part of my javascript:

```
...
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', this.files[0]);
formData.append('target_name', targetname);
formData.append('target_id', $('#mediaTargetId').val());
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$.ajax({
  url: "/admin/uploadMedia",
  type: "POST",             
  data: formData, 
  contentType: false,       
  cache: false,             
  processData:false,   
  beforeSend: function(){
}
...
```

And PHP (Laravel) that received this POST (here is the example just to check that data has been received):

```
public function uploadMedia() {
    return Input::get('target_name', 'no-target');
}
```

And some phpinfo():

```
post_max_size   8M
upload_max_filesize 2M
file_uploads    On
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
```

With this settings remote host return Error 500 until I comment out this:

```
formData.append('image', this.files[0]);
```

Hope you can help me and thank you in advance!

Comment: look at the server's error logs for details about the 500. that should be the FIRST place you check when you get a 500.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MarcB, I've fix it after checking error log. The reason of my Error 500 was "fcgidmaxrequestlen" parameter with this message in error log:

```
mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 137536 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)
```

So I can not upload files larger than 128kb. The solution is in httpd config file:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf - Path for CentOS
```

Just edit it with your favourite editor (vim, nano, etc.) and change or add this line into config:

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 10485760
```

Now it limits up to 10Mb. Then restart httpd service:

```
service httpd restart
```

And it's done. Once again, thanks @MarcB for idea.